# Python: Binary search tree and recursion returning a nested list

Tags: python, recursion, tree, binary-search-tree, inorder

Given a Binary Search Tree, for example:

```
        9
            8
    7
5
    3
        2
```

I would like to get an in-order list of nodes with values between a and b (inclusive).

I have implemented a recursive helper function:

```
def _range(root, a, b):
node_list = []
if root.left:
    node_list.append(_range(root.left, a, b))
if root.value >= a and root.value <= b:
    node_list.append(root)
if root.right:
    node_list.append(_range(root.right, a, b))
return node_list
```

Which gives me:

```
[[[BTNode: 2], BTNode: 3], BTNode: 5, [BTNode: 7, [[BTNode: 8], BTNode: 9]]]
```

I however need:

```
[BTNode: 2, BTNode: 3, BTNode: 5, BTNode: 7, BTNode: 8, BTNode: 9]
```

Is there anyway to flatten the list? I realize that what I am doing is appending a list to another list, but am not sure how to fix this without breaking the code.

Comment: Did you try to use `node_list.extend` instead of `node_list.append`?
An other solution would be to pass the list as parameter.

Comment: It took me a while to figure out that your tree is drawn from left to right instead of top to down. That was quite confusing… ^^

Answer (score 0):

`append` adds the object that you pass as argument to the list, so you obviously end up with nested lists. You want to concatenate the results, so you want to use `list.extend`(or the `+=` operator):

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> class Node(namedtuple('Node', 'value left right')):
...     # I reimplement __str__ just to avoid too much output later
...     def __repr__(self):
...             return 'Node(%r)' % self.value
...     __str__ = __repr__
... 
>>> def make_node(value, left=None, right=None):
...     return Node(value, left, right)
... 
>>> def _range(root, a, b):
...     node_list = []
...     if root.left:
...             node_list.extend(_range(root.left, a, b))
...     if a <= root.value <= b:
...             node_list.append(root)
...     if root.right:
...             node_list.extend(_range(root.right, a, b))
...     return node_list
... 
>>> tree = make_node(5, make_node(3, make_node(2)), make_node(7, None, make_node(8, None, make_node(9))))
>>> _range(tree, 1, 3)
[Node(2), Node(3)]
>>> _range(tree, 1, 10)
[Node(2), Node(3), Node(5), Node(7), Node(8), Node(9)]
```

An other way of doing it would be to pass the list around as a parameter:

```
>>> def _range(root, a, b, node_list=None):
...     if node_list is None:
...             # Note: do *not* use "[]" as a default!
...             node_list = []
...     if root.left:
...             _range(root.left, a, b, node_list)
...     if a <= root.value <= b:
...             node_list.append(root)
...     if root.right:
...             _range(root.right, a, b, node_list)
...     return node_list
... 
>>> _range(tree, 1, 3)
[Node(2), Node(3)]
>>> _range(tree, 1, 10)
[Node(2), Node(3), Node(5), Node(7), Node(8), Node(9)]
```